# how to make a build_script for ffmpeg library in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I tried many examples about building ffmpeg library, but failed for now. I checked my path and edited some code lines. I don't understand what's the problem in my build_android script. I set the build_android.sh in ffmpeg folder. And edited configure file. I'm running this at ubuntu. My ffmpeg version is 4.3.1 . here is my file. please I'm struggling this for 2 weeks...

*configure*

```
Original

SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR) $(SLIBNAME)'
 
 
Modified

SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)-$(LIBMAJOR)$(SLIBSUF)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME)'
```

*build_android.sh*

```
NDK=/home/ckdrb/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-16/arch-arm
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPU=arm
 
ISYSROOT=$NDK/sysroot
ASM=$ISYSROOT/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
 
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
 
function build_android
{
./configure \
    --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --arch=arm \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG    
make clean 
make 
make install
}
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm" 
build_android
```

*Error message*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved this using two ways.

first is removing disable-ffserver.

second is installing `sudo apt-get install yasm`